# ActiveRecord not saving complete nested data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have the following models:

```
class Innovator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :innovators_medios, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
  has_many :medios, :through => :innovators_medios
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :innovators_medios, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a['medio_id'].eql? 0 || a['medio_id'].blank? }

  attr_accessor :list_medios

  def self.nuevo
    @new = self.new

    @new.list_medios = Medio.all

    @new.list_medios.count.times { @nuevo.innovators_medios.build }

    @new
  end
end

class InnovatorsMedio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :innovator
  belongs_to :medio

  set_primary_key :medio_id
end
```

The controller:

```
class InnovadorsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @innovator  = Innovator.nuevo
  end

  ...
end
```

And the following view for new innovator:

```
<% form_for @innovator do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  ...  

  <section id="paso-1">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Datos del postulante</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">      
        ...                 
        <%= render :partial => 'datos_personales', :locals => { :dato => f } %>   
        ...   
    </div>      
  </section>
<% end %>
```

And the corresponding partials:

```
  ...
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= dato.label :innovadors_medios_id, '¿Cómo se enteró del programa de estímulo a la innovación e investigación?' %>
    <div class="input">
      <ul class="inputs-list">
      <% i = 0 %>
      <% dato.fields_for :innovadors_medios do |im| %>
        <%= render :partial => 'medios/new', :locals => { :medio => im, :nombre => @innovator.list_medios[i].nombre, :id => @innovator.list_medios[i].id } %>
        <% i += 1 %>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    ...

<li id="medio-<%= id %>">
  <label>
    <%= medio.check_box :medio_id, {}, id, 0 %>
    <span><%= nombre %></span>
  </label>
</li>
```

Everything renders as should be. However, when I save the record, AR doesn't save the nested attribute in the corresponding model. It only saves the primary id. ie:

```
   innovators_medios
-------------------------
 innovator_id | medio_id
-------------------------
       23     |
       23     |
       23     |
       23     |
-------------------------
```

The log console shows `WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: medio_id`

What could be wrong?

Comment: The app is on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're using a protected attribute from InnovatorsMedio class. Rails define some kind of accesibility for protect fields from mass-assigning.

Try to put `attr_accessible :medio_id` on your InnovatorsMedio class and tell if that fix your issue.

Comment: I have done it. But it block's the others attributes. An doesn't even save that attr. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try `attr_accessible :medio_id, :innovator_id`.

From attr_accessible doc:

> Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via
>   mass-assignment.
>
> Like attr_protected, a role for the attributes is optional, if no role
>   is provided then :default is used. A role can be defined by using the
>   :as option.
>
> This is the opposite of the attr_protected macro: Mass-assignment will
>   only set attributes in this list, to assign to the rest of attributes
>   you can use direct writer methods. This is meant to protect sensitive
>   attributes from being overwritten by malicious users tampering with
>   URLs or forms. If you’d rather start from an all-open default and
>   restrict attributes as needed, have a look at attr_protected.

Answer (score 0):

The :through docs suggest that the :primary_key option is ignored for through tables:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

And this older post (there are others) points to the possibility that setting the primary key in a through table did not work as of as late as 2.3.8 (or later):

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=36186

Although it seems that your error message is pointing to something else.